# SQL - Joining on subquery condition

Tags: mysql, sql

In my database I have two tables:

**Action**

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| lead_id      | int(11)      | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| type         | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**Lead**

```
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| status  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lead_id | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Lead table is somewhat unusual because leads are non-unique and identified by `lead_id`, so there can be several leads with the same `lead_id`.

What I'd like to do is to retrieve all actions and then join them with respective leads **on the condition** that they're the most recent (`MAX(created)`?).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853916/self-joining-table-view) answer partially explains how deal with leads table, however I can't find out how to make a join on a subquery the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this.  The following puts the condition in the `on` clause:

```
select a.*
from lead l join
     action a
     on l.lead_id = a.lead_id and
        l.created = (select MAX(created) from leads l2 where l2.lead_id = l.lead_id)
```

You can also do this with an explicit aggregation subquery:

```
select a.*
from lead l join
     action a
     on l.lead_id = a.lead_id  join
     (select lead_id, max(created) as maxcreated
      from lead l
      group by lead_id
    ) lmax
    on lmax.lead_id = l.lead_id and lmax.maxcreated = l.created;
```

Comment: Won't both of these exclude actions that don't have any matching leads?  As I read the question, the OP wanted all the actions, independent of what the matching leads might be.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin . . . I do not read the question that way.  There can't be a "most recent lead" if it is not in the lead table.  The confusion probably comes from the bad naming in the data structure.  The date/time is in the `lead` table, not the `action` table.

Comment: The date/time being in the `lead` table seems completely natural to me.  The situation I'm referring to is when there is a `lead_id` in the action table and no entries whatsoever with that `lead_id` in the `lead` table. The question asked for *all* action entries. The join with the `lead` table was the part that was conditional.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, the outer vs. inner join question aside, I would appreciate any feedback on my proposed answer either in terms of correctness or performance. I don't consider myself an SQL expert by any means.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin . . . To me, the statement "What I'd like to do is to retrieve all actions and then join them with respective leads on the condition that they're the most recent (MAX(created)?)" is very clear that each action needs a lead to get the most recent one.  I understand your point, but I interpret the question differently.

Answer (score 0):

Not verified, but I think you want something like the following:

```
select action.*, max_leads.* from action left join
  (select lead_id, max(created) from lead group by lead_id) max_leads
  on action.lead_id = max_leads.lead_id
```